# Bayesian models with categorical but non-binary observations

Tags: bayesian

This is a very general question concerning Bayesian model design. I would like to construct a model that predicts a subject's performance in an experiment. The model will have a number of free parameters that influence the subject's decision on each trial, and I want to estimate those parameter values via Bayesian inference.

If the experiment has a binary outcome on each trial (eg was the trial correct or incorrect), I would code these as a vector of Bernoulli random variables, with input p being determined by the free parameters in some way. However, what if I have four independent possible response outcomes per trial that at not ordinal? What probability distribution should be assigned to the observations in this circumstance?

Comment: Are the outcomes exclusive, dependent, independent?

Comment: Exclusive (meaning only one can occur?) and independent

Comment: Yes. Could you edit so the description of your data is more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in some variation on the basic Dirichlet/categorical model, described as:

\begin{align*}
p & \sim \text{dirichlet}(\alpha) \\
x \, | \, p & \sim \text{categorical}(p)
\end{align*}

This is a generalization of a [standard conjugate Bayesian model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181383/understanding-the-beta-conjugate-prior-in-bayesian-inference-about-a-frequency/181405#181405) for binary outcomes.

As an example, consider a [symmetric Dirichlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Special_cases) prior with concentration parameter $\alpha_0 = (1, 1, 1)$ and observe a sample of observations $1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2$.  Due to conjugacy, the posterior distribution is also a Dirichlet distribution with concentration parameter $\alpha = (2, 5, 6)$, and so you get that the posterior mean is $\left(\frac{2}{13}, \frac{5}{13}, \frac{6}{13}\right)$.